# Running Tshark in background

Tags: linux, wireshark, command-line-interface, tshark

I am trying to capture traffic with tshark from the CLI with something like this:

```
tshark -i 1 -w Outputfile.pcap
```

If I execute this command the prompt does not return as the tshark provides me with information on packet count and saves the packet info in the file "Outputfile.pcap". 
What I want is to get the prompt back, if possible. So, that I could execute more commands without opening up another terminal on the remote server. I have tried using the "&" at the end to run the process in background, the command prompt returns but the packet count continues to overwrite the commands that I am typing and I can not see anything :(

Does anyone know a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tshark -i 1 -w Outputfile.pcap -q &` instead.  The `-q` flag says to be super-quiet and & will run the process in the background so that the command prompt will not get overwritten

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! '-q' works instead. All I have to do afterwards is to go and kill the tshark process after getting it's pid. However, is there any particular command to stop a previously running tshark process without knowing its pid?

Comment: In reply to my previous comment. I guess pkill <process_name> can be used if there are no more than one process running with that name